# Socket server shuts off after 2-3 days

Tags: node.js, sockets, laravel, forever

I am using laravel and socket IO for real time communication. 
I installed node, express, socket IO and forever using npm in the root directory.

command to start file:

```
sudo forever start socket.js
```

[image: It shows following warning]

Scripts run for few days(2-3). After this it stops.

Any suggestion to fix this.

Comment: It is unlikely anyone can help you with this little information to go on.  You need to do your own investigation, looking at possible causes, collecting log info, etc... and then when you have a lot more info to share about what you investigated and what you saw that made you suspicious, you can post all that and see if people here can help you take it from there.  The first step is to gather a bunch of info on what might be going wrong (memory leaks, socket leaks, file handle leaks, server crashes, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Forever logs all errors by default, you can check the log file in `~/.forever/****.log`.

My guess would be that there is an error like:

`error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL`.

I had a simular issue with forever, using [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) as nodejs taskmanager solved my problem.

Comment: In the root directory(/var/www/html) I used following command to install 1) sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
2) npm install socket.io
3) npm install express
4) npm install ioredis
5) sudo npm install forever -g
6) sudo forever start socket.js
I am unable to find out any logs ( using sudo forever logs socket.js). Could you tell me what changes need to be done to so that it can be used for production